# replace with non zero value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array

```
Array
(
    [2013-08-12] => Array
        (
            [count] => 0
        )

    [2013-08-11] => Array
        (
            [count] => 5
        )

    [2013-08-10] => Array
        (
            [count] => 0
        )

    [2013-08-09] => Array 
        (
            [count] =>3
        )
    [2013-08-08] => Array 
        (
            [count] =>0
        )
    [2013-08-07] => Array 
        (
            [count] =>0
        )
)
```

Now this is actually a running total. So in my view file I need to display the counts in such a way that it should display the non-zero value if available and otherwise zero.

In this case the count starts on 2013-08-08 and so it is okay to display 0 for the dates before it. But for the dates after it, it needs to display the previous count if there is no count for the date.

So for 2013-08-10 it needs to display the count as 3 and for 12th it should be . It is is the total of some user signup and so if the count for one date is zero, it needs to display the total up to that date. how can I do this ?

Comment: Have you tried to solve this yourself? Please post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty basic:

Just loop through your array, adding the count value to a running total, and displaying that running total:

```
$runningTotal = 0;
foreach($myArray as $key => $value) {
    echo $key, ' => ';
    $runningTotal += $value['count'];
    echo $runningTotal, PHP_EOL;
}
```

but make sure your array is in order first

```
ksort($myArray);
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment:

```
$runningTotal = 0;
foreach($myArray as $key => $value) {
    echo $key, ' => ';
    $runningTotal += $value['count'];
    echo ($value['count'] > 0) ? $value['count'] : $runningTotal;
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

**EDIT #2**

Based on subsequent comment:

```
$runningTotal = 0;
foreach($myArray as $key => $value) {
    echo $key, ' => ';
    $runningTotal = ($value['count'] > 0) ? $value['count'] : $runningTotal;
    echo $runningTotal, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: But the $value['count'] is actually running total fetched from DB so adding it will give false results. For eg : this will give 8 as count for the dy following the count 5. But it needs to be 5 itself.

Comment: So you expect to see `2013-08-07 0; 2013-08-08 0; 2013-08-09 3; 2013-08-10 3; 2013-08-11 5; 2013-08-12 8;`? See edit... though it's hard to believe that count is a running total from your data when it shows 3 dropping to 0 the following day.... unless 3 people have deleted their accounts

Comment: I actually need 2013-08-07 0; 2013-08-08 0; 2013-08-09 3; 2013-08-10 3; 2013-08-11 5; 2013-08-12 5;